# prevent direct access to php page (refresh not count)

Tags: php

I want to prevent the user from directly accessing to a page called member.php, and whenever he tries i redirect him to login.php.
i tried putting :

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['fromLogin']='true';
```

in login.php and :

```
session_start();

if($_SESSION['fromLogin'] == 'false'){
header('location: login.php');
}else{
    $_SESSION['fromLogin']='false';
}
```

in member.php.
It works but when i'm in member.php and i refresh the page it takes me to login.php. i want to stay in member.php. 
Thanks !

Comment: Remove the else part (and by the way, remove the quotes around `'false'` and `'true'` you can use boolean values instead of string)

Comment: Exactly... Remove the else part! Because if the session value is true, why turn it into false?

Comment: then if i click Logout on membre.php , i can access it by typing it in the url and that's a problem.  i want the only way to access it is by login.php

Comment: On logout click, then it's the time to turn the `$_SESSION['fromLogin']` to false... Using ajax may be a way... It depends on what you already have for that logout click.

Comment: i tried putting else part after logout click but still doesn't work

Comment: PHP runs on server-side... And the click handler is runned on client-side. It means two different moment in time (by milliseconds...) Read [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/171203/what-are-the-differences-between-server-side-and-client-side-programming)

Answer (score 0):

Has the user already login and you want to prevent him from the member.php or he has not login yet.
If he has already login, then you should create a role in you database (admin and non_admin) then you collect that role when login. **$_SESSION['role']=$row['role'];**
Then you created a separate admin authentication then include it in the *member.php* file
**if($_SESSION['role']!='admin'){ redirect code here }**

But if the user don't login, that one is normal athentication
**if($_SESSION['role']==NULL || $_SESSION['role']==false ){ redirect code here }**

Hope it helps you in some way.